# DbContextOptionsBuilder could not be found ASP.NET Core 1.1 Web API project

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add Entity Framework Core 1.1 to my project and use a connection String to get my data from a Azure database. I tried reading the changes on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/ where they say, that i should do this in my Startup.cs file to connect to the DB:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer(
            "connection string",
            options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure());
}
```

But it just gives me an error:

> The type or namespace 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could not be found...

and

> 'Startup.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder): No suitable method
>   found to override.

I can add **using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;** which will make the error with DbContextOptionsBuilder disappear, but then the **.UseSqlServer** is getting an error:

> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'UseSqlServer' and no extension method ...

This is my dotnet.csproj file
[image: dotnet.csproj]

How to fix this problem, so i can connect to my Db on Azure and get the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your project.json content and your DbContext class ?

Comment: There's no project.json file. Which one are you thinking about @H. Harzl?

Since this is placed in my Startup.cs, there's no DbContext class. Do i have to restructure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog post you're referring to might be a bit confusing. They're talking about the OnConfiguring method of your **DbContext** *or* some place in your Startup. Your example is mixing both worlds (you expect the DbContext OnConfiguring method to be in the Startup).

First add the package *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer*.

Let's say you want to use Startup.cs, it will look like this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
    }
```

You can define your connection string in the appsettings.json:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.;Database=<your db>;User Id=;Password="
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I still get an error with the **options.UseSqlServer** part. I have added the package, so how do i solve this problem?

Comment: 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer' and no extension method 'UseSqlServer' Accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found..

Comment: No need for DbContextOptionsBuilder here. Did you copy above ConfigureServices method into your Startup? It has no DbContextOptionsBuilder, so remove any old code that references to it.

Comment: Now it's working! Now if you don't mind, how do i then print some data out from my database to the website? If you got a link or something like that :)

Comment: I did this, but my controllers data is never assigned. Guess this is the wrong way of doing it.

http://imgur.com/a/kvTq5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138831/discussion-between-kloarubeek-and-fillah).